# Zune software is not launched (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I installed VS 2010 Express + WP7 SDK, it worked perfectly. Now I need to use unit-tests, and installed VS 2010 Ultimate (and reinstalled WP7 SDK). WP7 plugin seems to be installed (there are WP7 project types in "New Project" dialog), but when I'm trying to launch my software for debug, VS says that "Error    1   Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched.". WP7 emulator is already launched (and Zune too, but Zune says, that there is no device connected). Expression Blend works with emulator perfectly (it runs the emulator by itself). Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you have the Standard toolbar visible. That's where you select the Target Device. To do this: **View** -> **Toolbars** -> **Standard**. Since Expression Blend detects the emulator, then there is a problem with Visual Studio, that tries to deploy to a device by default.

**REMEMBER:** *Zune Software is not required to be running when you are deploying to an emulator.*

Second, try to create a **new** Windows Phone 7 project and try deploying it from Visual Studio to see how it works.

Comment: >> First of all, make sure that you have the Standard toolbar visible - Oh, of course, Standard toolbar was hidden...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Visual Studio tries to deploy to a device.
Did you select "Windows Phone 7 Emulator" in the "Target Deployment Device" dropdown?

Comment: I don't see this option at all. Here is my screenshot: [link](http://habreffect.ru/files/367/e22f77a98/vs2010_no_wp7_options.png)

Comment: This option is supposed to be in the VS toolbar and yours seems to be missing a lot of options. You should try to reset your toolbar: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/07/27/reset-toolbars-vstipenv0029.aspx